# How does java's thread work in memory

Tags: java, multithreading

As we know,java thread work with own memory.It copy the member from main-men to own-men.Is it deep-copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java threads only have their own memory for:

1. Data that goes on the stack (ie stacktrace and method primatives and object handles)
2. Objects that are declared ThreadLocal

All other data is placed in the Heap and is shared by any thread that has a reference to it